# Load big wfs layer in R

Tags: r, wfs, big-data

i´m trying to load the layer `Mroad_Lden_17` into R with the code below:

```
proj_folder <- "C:/Users/... "
setwd(proj_folder)

# helper function for querying uba
load_laerm <- function(what) {
    filename <- file.path(proj_folder, paste0(what, ".RData"))
    if(!file.exists(filename)) {
        message("building ", filename)
        wfs_laerm <- "https://datahub.uba.de/server/services/INSPIRE/end/MapServer/WFSServer?"
        laerm_client <- ows4R::WFSClient$new(wfs_laerm, serviceVersion = "2.0.0")
        laerm_url <- httr::parse_url(laerm_client$url)
        laerm_url$query <- list(
            service = "wfs", version = "2.0.0", request = "GetFeature",
            typename = paste0("INSPIRE_end:", what), srsName = "EPSG:3857"
        )
        request <- httr::build_url(laerm_url)
        ans <- sf::read_sf(request)
        save(ans, file=filename)
    } else {
        message("loading from ", basename(filename))
        load(filename)
    }
    stopifnot(inherits(ans, "sf"),  inherits(ans, "data.frame"))
    message("==> ", what, " loaded.")
    return(ans)
}
Mroad_Lden_17 <- load_laerm("Mroad_Lden_17")
```

Unfortunately, the layer is really big, and R needs much time to load it, e.g. it stops the loading process, because the layer is too big with its 809559 features. I thought about a way to load the layer in "smaller pieces" and put it togther afterwards, but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Not a heavy R user but what you want is called paging. An issue is opened at https://github.com/eblondel/ows4R/issues/29 and although it remains open it seems to have been implemented (https://github.com/eblondel/ows4R/blob/master/R/WFSFeatureType.R#L230) but only at the moment in master branch, not in any release.

If you are unhappy with the implementation, you can always call `ogr2ogr` GDAL utility wrapped in R combined with environment variables like at [Inconsistencies in features count retrieved while consuming a WFS webservice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387370/inconsistencies-in-features-count-retrieved-while-consuming-a-wfs-webservice) (PS: I self quote my working example where the remote service had some issues)